# Regex matching pattern but when it's not on the beginning of string

Tags: regex

How do I match a pattern (in my case it's new line character) but not when it's on the very beginning of the string.

So I need something like `/\n/` but matching only second and third new line characters in the following string `\nthis is a line\nand the second one\nand the third one`

Comment: Just add a `(?!^)` or `(?<!^)` before `\n`.

Comment: It depends on the language you are ultimately using...

Comment: multiline flag?

Comment: @I'L'I I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I didn't know about lookaheads.